# How to stop listbox auto select?

Tags: c#

When `listbox` is loaded and when `DataSource`is changed `listbox` trigger selected index changed function. How to avoid triggering this function?
I tried this :

> somelistbox.SelectedIndex = -1;

When this has been added, `listbox` does not select first element(at least it is not visible in UI), but it triggers the function for selected index like first element is choosen.

Comment: You can simply check the SelctedIndex and return immidiately, if it's -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a guard.

```
private bool _isSelectionEnabled = true;
```

In the event handler

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_isSelectionEnabled) {
        // Put selection logic here.
    }
}
```

When setting the data source

```
_isSelectionEnabled = false;
try {
    listBox1.DataSource = datasource;
} finally {
    _isSelectionEnabled = true;
}
```

The try-finally ensures that the flag is reset in any case, even if an exception should occur.

You can do this also when setting the `SelectedIndex` in code, if you don't want the logic to be triggered.